# How to group and then pivot data

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to group and then pivot some data to display on asp.net view.

Here is my View Model class.

```
public class myModel
{

    public string id { get; set; }
    public string fund{ get; set; }
    public string account{ get; set; }
    public string amount{ get; set; }
```

}

Here is a sample data returned from database

```
id   fund       account   amt
1     101       1001      25.70
2     101       1001      10.00
3     101       1001      12.00
4     101       1002      -5.0
5     201       2001      12.00
6     201       2001      11.00
```

Now I have a query that returns above data and maps it to the model mentioned above. Essentially I have a list of objects with above mentioned data.

Now I want to group and sum this data and display like below in my view.

```
fund
    account      sum of all amt
    account       sum of all amt
fund
    account       sum of all amt
    account       sum of all amt
```

so something like

```
101
   1001      47.00
   1002      -5

   ....
201
   2001   23

and so on
```

How do I go about doing this?

I have a list of objects as mentioned above.

I'm thinking of creating another class and them mapping to it but I'm perhaps making it more complicated than it needs to be

```
public class pivot
{
        public string fund { get; set; }
        public List < pivotdetail >detail{ get; set; }
 }

public class pivotdetail
{
       pretty obvious
}
```

Any ideas on how I can do this or I should approach this?

Comment: Have you tried LINQ? You might find this link helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a grouping of a grouping. First, group at the deepest level, then group those groups going up levels to get the structure you want.

```
from x in Data
group x.Amount by new { x.Fund, x.Account } into g
group new
{
    g.Key.Account,
    Amount = g.Sum(),
} by g.Key.Fund
```

Note that this will usually be inefficient as it will create new queries for every group. You might want to restrict it to a single grouping call on the database and further group in code.

```
from g in (from x in Data
          group x.Amount by new { x.Fund, x.Account } into g
          select new
          {
            g.Key.Fund,
            g.Key.Account,
            Amount = g.Sum()
          }).AsEnumerable()
group new
{
    g.Account,
    g.Amount,
} by g.Fund;
```

Comment: I'm getting "IGrouping<<anonymous type: string fund, string account>, string>' does not contain a definition for 'Sum' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Sum(IQueryable<int>)' "... This is for g.Sum(); the x.amount is decimal but the result is stored as var

Comment: Be sure to read the `amount` field as a decimal, otherwise convert to it. If read in as a string, this wouldn't work.

Comment: I changed from var to class and it's still giving the same error. A bit of googling seems to suggest that sum can't be projected.